# Property of INF-w_i Composition of Fuzzy Relation

Tags: fuzzy-set

For any $\mathit a, b, d $ $\epsilon$ $\left[0,1\right]$, $\mathit a$ $\leq$ $\mathit b$ $\Rightarrow$ $$\\$$ i$\left.\right)$ $\omega_i$ $\left(a, d\right)$ 
 $\geq$ $\omega_i$ $\left(b,d\right)$ $$\\$$ ii$\left.\right)$ $\omega_i$ $\left(d,a\right)$ $\leq$ $\omega_i$ $\left(d,b\right)$

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: To prove the assertion..